# ggtext axis title show one letter on top of another

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggtext

I'm rendering axis title with `ggtext` using `axis.title.y = element_markdown(size = 5, face = "bold")`, but it seems to interpret the space wrongly when exported as png image as in the picture below (the last letter of one word is in the same place of the first letter of the next word).

The real title is: "Compuestos orgánicos volátiles (µg/m<sup>3</sup>)" but it is not displayed well.

Any idea on how to fix this?.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Fixed with `remotes::install_github("wilkelab/gridtext")`